# PDO order by DESC with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got a nice database with users, they all got money.
Check out this example:

```
Jan - 200€ 
Piet - €199.1983091389013 
Karel - €300
```

When i do a simple script like this one:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `gebruikers` ORDER BY geld DESC LIMIT 10'); 
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchall();
foreach ($result as $gebruiker) {
    $gebruikergeld = round($gebruiker['geld'], 2);
    echo "<li>".$gebruiker['naam']." - &euro; ".$gebruikergeld."</li>";
}
```

Now i get this returned:

```
Piet - €199.2
Karel - €300
Jan - €200
```

As you see, its kinda weird, he isn't counting the dot.
So he sees `€199.2` as `€1992`.

Someone got this before or knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What data type is geld?

Comment: I think you should drop the coin symbol from the DB and change the field's type to INT. Otherwise, php would treat it as a string.

Comment: @kainaw Im saving geld as a varchar(50)

Comment: Tip: always save geld as decimal, OR as an integer with a second column that holds the centiemen.

Comment: @Chiel Then "desc" will mean "descending character ordering" using character codes. It will not treat it as a numeric value. If the column is supposed to hold numeric values, make it numeric. Clean the data when you insert it and you won't have to clean it when you extract it.

Comment: @kainaw So changing it to a INT in the struture will fix it, or wil it remove the decimals?

Comment: @Chiel Changing it to an int will drop the decimal values. I'm not sure why you are wanting it to be an int. You can make it decimal to make it numeric and keep the decimal values. NOTE: Numeric and Int are not the same. Numeric means 'any number' while int means 'non-decimal numbers'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the data to int for ordering

```
SELECT * FROM `gebruikers` 
ORDER BY geld+0 DESC LIMIT 10
```

If the symbol is stored you may do as

```
SELECT * FROM `gebruikers` 
 ORDER BY replace(geld,'€','')+0 DESC LIMIT 10
```

But the better idea would be to store amount as integer datatype and with an additional column for the currency symbol

Comment: I used your first method and it works fine! Saving the currency symbol wouldn't be needed. Why should I?

Comment: I was unware of your data so I made a guess you might be saving it, so is the 2nd solution.